# How to properly use a callback function with jQuery's document.ready

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

So I recently found that this js doesn't work on JSFiddle. Please help! My code is simple, yet it still doesn't seem to work! Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready{

alert("hey");

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you load jQuery? You probably didn't.

Comment: Yes, I clicked the play button - if that's what you mean.

Comment: What is more probable, that a tool used by a whole lot of people has secretly been not working at all, or that you are doing something wrong ? Post a link to a jsfiddle that doesn't work so we can identify the issue.

Comment: Blender is right, check left menu of fiddle, at top there is a select by default on "no library (pure js)" just change the value to jquery

Comment: It should be `.ready(function(){ /* code */ });`. Make sure you load jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/8t3DK/ . Remember to check your console for errors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is simply a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error, your code is missing an `(`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

And an other reason may be that you aren't loading jQuery in your fiddle. To do so, on the sidebar click the dropdown menu and select one of the jQuery items.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, no still doesn't work...

Comment: yes, and jsfiddle not need the user to wrap his code in .load or .ready, the left menu second select let user choice init event

Comment: Should be `$(document).ready(function(){` or `$(function(){`. http://jsfiddle.net/jf6bv/

Comment: Hmm no stil doesn't work

Comment: @DJDavid98 sure, but it's redondant, and in case of complex coding this can be very different

Comment: @user2533448 just compare this fiddle to your one > http://jsfiddle.net/r043v/gXbjE/